# Export CSV NOT showing ALL Prods - using Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product, csv, importexport

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.2.

When I do a Product Export CSV, NOT all the Products are exported to CSV.

However, when use the Data Profile > Export All Products, the output CSV is correct.

I prefer doing Import/Export > Export instead using DataProfiles, bcoz the output CSV is easier to analyse.

What could be the reason for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add some filtering in when exporting via Admin -> Import/Export -> Export. It gives option to reduce the size of exported catalog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) 
to import or upload bulk amount of product ..

This project is an attempt to provide a product importer for magento that can handle several thousands of products at a reasonable pace compared to magento dataflow. it may evolve to a dataflow alternative as new features are implemented.